# Cosette related to Amanda Seyfried in Google Search?

Tags: google-search

I like Les Mis and Cosette, so when I googled Cosette, the results like this:

[image: Cosette Mingey]

Why Google Search related Cosette keyword to her potrayer, Isabelle Allen and Amanda Seyfried? Any relationship between them and Cosette?

Comment: Please show your search/research efforts. Reference [ask].

Comment: I had included screenshot above as my effort, sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have answered your own question:

> Any relationship between them and Cosette?

with

> related Cosette keyword to her potrayer, Isabelle Allen and Amanda Seyfried

The two portrayed Cosette (at different ages) in 2012 in the film adaptation of Les Misérables.

This is the start of the former's Wikipedia entry:

> Isabelle Lucy Allen (born 16 March 2002) is an English stage and screen teen actress known for her role as the young Cosette in the 2012 film adaptation of Les Misérables.

and this included in the latter's:

> Later that year, she played Cosette in the film adaptation of the musical Les Misérables.

Google `cosette played by` and these are the first two images:

[image: Cosette images]

Both are the most recent entries for films at [Les Misérables Wiki](http://lesmiserables.wikia.com/wiki/Cosette_-_list_of_portrayers). And so on throughout the Internet. There are very many pages on which  `Cosette` and `Seyfried` appear together and very many pages on which `Cosette` and `Isabelle Allen` appear together. Google's indexing system has noted such "pairs" and when you asked for one of the pair it has offered you the choice of the other.

Google will also be aware the search terms are connected because of the number of people who used search terms such as `cosete sayfried`, `allan les mis` and innumerable other combinations.`

Comment: Did you mean people used search term such as "cosette seyfried" and "allen les mis"? Seem like there's a typo in your answers which might affect the results when people search your mistyped search terms.

Comment: Oh like that sir

Comment: So anything can be related?